# Google maps api styled map with satellite water

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I am using google maps API V3 to create a styled map where I am using custom colors.  I am wondering if it is possible to use the satellite image of the water while using a custom style on the land. I.e. I'd like the water to be the satellite image while the land will be a custom solid color.  Right now I can give the land and the water a custom color, but I'm wondering if I can assign the water styling somehow to come from the satellite imagery.

I don't think this is possible from digging through the API but just making sure I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment that is not possible. The [Google Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) cannot be applied to map types other than the default `ROADMAP` type. This was confirmed by a Google Employee on the mailing list on May 31st 2010:

- [Google Maps API v3 Re: Using Styled Maps with TERRAIN map type?](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-js-api-v3@googlegroups.com/msg03870.html)

> ... We don't currently support styling other map types, because we can not
>   recolour the base imagery right now...

Comment: Awesome, thanks for finding this. Hopefully this is something thats implemented in the future.