# Google Styled Maps can be applied to SATELLITE map type?

Tags: google-maps-styling

Here it is said that was not possible in 2012 [Google maps api styled map with satellite water](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918608/google-maps-api-styled-map-with-satellite-water). Now it is?
I've tried https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com, not working on satellite...

Can be used something like custom overlayer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want to apply a style to raster imagery? Only water in the image?

Comment: @chb: My client wants something to make Satellite Map look exciting and engaging, another colour for water, greener hills... :) . But I don't think it is possible, from my searching. The answers bellow confirms. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is said in the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling).

> Styling works only on the normal map type.
>   Styling does not affect indoor maps.

Comment: Your answers confirms that it is not possible. Thanks.